# Is there a convention to the order of modifiers in C#?

Tags: c#

If I were to use more than one, what order should I use modifier keywords such as:

`public`, `private`, `protected`, `virtual`, `abstract`, `override`, `new`, `static`, `internal`, `sealed`, and any others I'm forgetting.

Comment: You missed out [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx), [`extern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx), [`unsafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx), [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx), and [`async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had a look at Microsoft's [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.100%29) and couldn't find any references to what order modifiers should be put on members. Likewise, a look at the [C# 5.0 language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029) proved fruitless. There were two other avenues to follow, though: [EditorConfig files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017) and [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper).

---

## .editorconfig

The MSDN page, [.NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017) says:

> In Visual Studio 2017, you can define and maintain consistent code style in your codebase with the use of an [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017) file.
>
> ## Example EditorConfig file
>
> To help you get started, here is an example .editorconfig file with the default options:
>
> ```
> ###############################
> # C# Code Style Rules         #
> ###############################
>
> # Modifier preferences
> csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public,private,protected,internal,static,extern,new,virtual,abstract,sealed,override,readonly,unsafe,volatile,async:suggestion
> ```

In other words: the default order for modifiers, following the default editorconfig settings is:

```
{ public / private / protected / internal / protected internal / private protected } // access modifiers
static
extern
new
{ virtual / abstract / override / sealed override } // inheritance modifiers
readonly
unsafe
volatile
async
```

---

### ReSharper

[ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), however, is more forthcoming. The defaults for ReSharper 2018.1<sup>1</sup>, with access modifiers (which are exclusive) and inheritance modifiers (which are exclusive), grouped together is:

```cs
{ public / protected / internal / private / protected internal / private protected } // access modifiers
new
{ abstract / virtual / override / sealed override } // inheritance modifiers
static
readonly
extern
unsafe
volatile
async
```

This is stored in the `{solution}.dotsettings` file under the

```
"/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/MODIFIERS_ORDER/@EntryValue"
```

node - the ReSharper default<sup>2</sup> is:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/MODIFIERS_ORDER/@EntryValue">
    public protected internal private new abstract virtual sealed override static readonly extern unsafe volatile async
</s:String>
```

<sup>1</sup> [ReSharper 2018.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/#v2018-1) says that it has "*Full understanding of C# 7.2*" and explicitly mentions the `private protected` access modifier.

<sup>2</sup> ReSharper only saves settings which differ from the default, so in general this node, as it is, will not be seen in the `dotsettings` file.

---

### `new static` vs `static new`

The MSDN page for [Compiler Warning CS0108](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8070fc.aspx) gives the example of a public field `i` on a base class being hidden by a public static field `i` on a derived class: their suggestion is to change `static` to `static new`:

> ```
> public class clx
> {
>     public int i = 1;
> }
>
> public class cly : clx
> {
>     public static int i = 2; // CS0108, use the new keyword
>     // Use the following line instead:
>     // public static new int i = 2;
> }
> ```

Likewise, the IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015 also suggests changing `static` to `static new`

[image: CS0108 Visual Studio recommended change]

which is the same if the field `i` in the base class is also `static`.

That said, a cursory search on GitHub found that some projects override this default to put `static` *before*, not *after* `new`, the inheritance modifiers and `sealed`, e.g.
[the ReSharper settings for StyleCop GitHub project](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Src/AddIns/ReSharper/StyleCop.dotSettings#L75):

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeStyle/CodeFormatting/CSharpFormat/MODIFIERS_ORDER/@EntryValue">
    public protected internal private static new abstract virtual override sealed readonly extern unsafe volatile async
</s:String>
```

however since `static` cannot be used in conjunction with the inheritance modifiers or `sealed`, this is just a distinction between `new static` (the default, and suggested by the default editorconfig file) and `static new` (suggested by ReSharper).

Personally I prefer the latter, but Google searches in [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for [`new static`](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=inurl:referencesource.microsoft.com%2F+%22new+static%22) vs [`static new`](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=inurl:referencesource.microsoft.com%2F+%22static+new%22) in 2015 and 2018 gave:

```
             (in 2015)  (in 2018)
new static   203        427
static new   10         990
```

which implies that the preference at Microsoft is `static new`.

Comment: This should be the selected answer as of 2019

Answer (score 22):

[StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com) is available as a [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop) or a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild) and can validate your source code against the rules some teams in Microsoft use.  StyleCop likes the access modifier to come first.

EDIT: Microsoft isn't itself totally consistent; different teams use different styles. For example StyleCop suggests putting using directives in the namespace, but this is not followed in the Roslyn source code.

Comment: Excellent answer. When ever possible, let something like StyleCop look after monitoring compliance with style guidelines, as it is so much more reliable than leaving it to us mere humans :)

Comment: StyleCop has rules that seem to differ from MS's prior style guides. For example, StyleCop hates m_ and _ for prefixs to private members. Also, the VS default code generation violates StyleCop by putting using statements outside the namespace. *sigh*

Comment: As a tip: Sorting the whole mess can be very annoying if you had another class structure before. Use CodeMaid, which can do it automatically.

Comment: I was under the impression that using statements behave differently depending on where you put them.

Answer (score 3):

I usually start off with the access modifier first, then virtual/abstract/sealed, then override/new/etc. although others might do it differently. Almost invariably, the access modifier will be first, however.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases there are very many possibilities. For example with the below class `C` with base class `B`,

```
public class B
{
  public void X()
  {
  }
}
public class C : B
{
  protected internal new static readonly DateTime X;
}
```

the field of type `DateTime` in `C` has no fewer than five distinct modifiers, so there are `5! == 5*4*3*2*1 == 120` different ways to write the same field! It would be *very* confusing not to have `protected` and `internal` next to each other, but it is still legal.

Not sure if everyone agrees on a convention for the order. For example I have seen some people put the `new` modifier *before* the access level (protection level) modifier, although many people like to always have the protection level modifier first.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there's no functional difference in how they are ordered, but just like with grammar, it sounds weird if it is out of order.

I've heard before there is a preferred order but couldn't find a C# guide that indicated it either, but there is this Language Rules code style to refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0036.