# Which is recommended: "static public" or "public static"

Tags: c#

If you have a class member that is `static` and `public`. Would you write `static public` or `public static`? I know they are the same. But is there some recommendation / best practice for writing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c#191944)

If you download the Microsoft [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) Visual Studio addin, it can validate your source code against the rules Microsoft use. It likes the access modifier to come first.

Comment: The new home for StyleCop referenced above seems to be [here](https://stylecop.codeplex.com)

Comment: The Roslyn-based [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) project is recommended for developers who use only Visual Studio 2015 or later.

Comment: ...and access modifiers are public, private, protected, etc.

Answer (score 41):

"public static" is far more common, so you might want to go with that just to increase readability for programmers who never stumbled upon "static public".

Answer (score 14):

When nothing else matters, go with consistency. In this case the rest of the world uses `public static`, so I'd go with that too just to avoid unnecessary surprise in those reading your code.

Answer (score 4):

I personally would go with public static because it's more important that it's public than that it's static.

And check this: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html

As well as this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html (These two links are for Java, but the concept is the same)

Short version: "public static" is recommended and is far more common.

Comment: -1 I don't agree the fact of a method is "public" is more important than it is "static". I believe exactly the opposite.

Comment: @Carlos i believe the question was about class member variables rather than methods. And though obviously both keywords are very important (and so a debate makes little sense), the visibility is by usual convention the first keyword to use, since it determines whether a member is reachable by other classes at all. Only once we know a member is visible/reachable is it obviously important HOW to reach it (where "static" becomes important).

Comment: I believe that static has more "impact" in a member than its own visibility. It changes it "meaning" completely, while visibility is just, more or less, a convention for accessing the member and it can be overcome with reflection. The fact that something is static has much more impact. That said, I sadly use "public static" due to its overwhelming popularity...