# Order of function modifiers in C#

Tags: syntax, c#-4.0

I would like to know if there is a standard to set the order of function modifiers in C#. i.e.

```
public static void Method()
{}

static public void Method()
{}
```

this both work well, BUT

when I code:

```
public void static Method()
{}
```

I receive the following error:

> Member modifier 'static' must precede
>   the member type and name

and

> Method must have a return type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a convention to the order of modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method declarations must always follow this pattern:

```
[modifiers] returnType methodName([parameters])
```

There is no rule regarding the order of modifiers, but they must always precede the return type.

I don't think there is any standard order, people just do as they please... Personally I prefer to put the access modifier (`public`, `private`, etc) first, then the `static` modifier (if any), then the `virtual`, `abstract` or `override` modifier (if applicable).

See the C# spec for details (§10.6)

Comment: Good points Thomas, please any other self-created "modifiers pattern"?

Comment: Thomas, could you please add a link to "See the C# spec for details (§10.6)". I have downloaded the specifications but haven't find them now.

Comment: There is no online version of the spec, so I can't post a direct link... In version 3.0 of the spec, §10.6 is on page 295

Comment: I was speaking about this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E Also, for C# 3.0 exists: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/csharp%20language%20specification.doc

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `void` isn't a modifier - it's the return type. All the modifiers have to come before the return type.

I'm pretty sure there *is* a convention for the ordering of genuine modifiers, but I don't know where it's documented.

I would always write the accessibility (public etc) first.

Comment: In the absence of a more official convention, I'd propose going by the order the modifiers are listed in the [specification (pg. 307)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552). `new public protected internal private static virtual sealed override abstract extern async`. I think that agrees with official MSDN examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific order for method modifiers.

Following is the formal grammar from the C# Standard specification ...

**Methods are declared using method-declarations:**
method-declaration:
method-header   method-body

**method-header:**
attributes*opt*   method-modifiers*opt*   partial*opt*   **return-type**   **member-name**   type-parameter-list*opt*
 (   formal-parameter-list*opt*   )  type-parameter-constraints-clauses*opt*

****method-modifiers:****
new
public
protected
internal
private
static
virtual
sealed
override
abstract
extern
**return-type:**
type
void
**member-name:**
identifier
interface-type   .   identifier