# Which modifier should go first?

Tags: java, coding-style, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java modifiers syntax and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050233/java-modifiers-syntax-and-format)

You can put modifiers of variables or methods in any order in Java, for example:

```
private static final int x;
static final private int y;
```

Both lines of code above work fine, and both declare an integer that is private, static, and final. My question is, what is the accepted/common standard for arranging them? What order should I put the modifiers in?

Comment: I think this answers the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7050233/422353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html (which gives links to the language specification)

The preferred order for your example is:

```
private static final int x;
```

Comment: Side Note: Since a "static final" variable is essentially a constant in Java, the coding convention would be for it to be in upper case: `private static final int X;`

Answer (score 1):

`private  static final int y` is probably better. It is the decreasing order of interest from outside of the class.

When you look at 'public-private' tell whether this method/variable is of any interest to any external client.

next is static. This is mostly a class context information.

Having final as last option- This information mostly needed only by class's method.

(I generally leave it my editor to sort the modifiers- it conforms to above order)

Answer (score 1):

I have made the same question but with .NET, and I received a really good answer that I want to share with you: [Order of function modifiers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749958/c-sharp-order-of-function-modifiers)
Hope that helps,

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are the standards for .NET the same as the standards for Java in most cases? And what about in this case?

Comment: More or less are the same, the most important is the concept, look in the link that the proposed order from Thomas Levesque is: access modifier (public, private, etc) first, then the static modifier (if any), then the virtual, abstract or override modifier (if applicable).

Answer (score -1):

I would say is the common way would be

```
private static int x;
```

Though I am not sure were you would put the final as the common way.

If I was doing it I would probably do it the way you had it though.

```
private static final int x;
```

Comment: Modded down because the asker asked for a accepted/common standard, and getting everybody's opinion and counting it out is not an option.