# "public static" vs "static public" - is there a difference?

Tags: c#, .net, static, standards, access-modifiers

```
sealed class PI
{
  public static float number;
  static PI()
  { number = 3.141592653F; }
  static public float val()
  { return number; }
}
```

1. What's the difference between public static and static public? Can they be used in any order?
2. How would I use `static public float val()`?

   Does it get executed as soon as the class is initialized?

Comment: A second question should probably be asked in a seperate question.

Comment: See also older thread [Is there a convention to the order of modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it is just like the name of a Person  =)
Calling Tom Mike or Mike Tom, no difference.

Comment: Except perhaps if you're Sing Confu and they call you Confu Sing.

Answer (score 27):

There's no difference. You're free to specify them in either order.
However, I find that most developers tend to use:

```
public static
```

and NOT static public.

Comment: Yes. Accessibility modifier first, by convention. Always.

Answer (score 9):

**About the ordering of modifiers**

They can be used in any order. It's just a stylistic choice which one you use. I always use visibility first, and most other code does too.

**About the second question:**

```
static public float val()
```

This is just a static function. You call it with `PI.val()`. You just don't need an instance of the class to call it, but call it on the class directly. A static function does not receive a `this` reference, can't be virtual, it's just like a function in a non OOP language, except that it's using the class as namespace.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference.  Their order is not important with respect to each other

Answer (score 5):

To answer your second question, it should probably be written as

```
public static class Pi
{
    private static float pi = 0;

    public static float GetValue()
    {
        if (pi == 0)
            pi = 3.141592653F;   // Expensive pi calculation goes here.

        return pi;
    }
}
```

And call it thusly:

```
float myPi = Pi.GetValue();
```

The reason for writing such a class is to cache the value, saving time on subsequent calls to the method.  If the way to get pi required a lot of time to perform the calculations, you would only want to do the calculations once.

Comment: Except pi cannot be null since it's a value type

Answer (score 4):

With regards to the second question: The method is available without an instance of a class, it could be called thusly:

```
PI.val();
```

Because the class only has static members, the class should probably be a static class, and then it could never get initialized.