# Ordering of virtual, abstract, override keywords

Tags: c#, .net

What is good coding practice regarding placing of keywords:

A.

```
    virtual public void VirMethod() {}
    abstract public void AbsMethod(); 

    ..
    override public void AbsMethod()
    {
      //..
    }
```

B.

```
    public virtual void VirMethod() {}
    public abstract void AbsMethod(); 

    ..
    public override void AbsMethod()
    {
      //..
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a convention to the order of modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c), [C# public static vs static public - is there a difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147668/c-sharp-public-static-vs-static-public-is-there-a-difference)

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same.

Most people write `public virtual` meaning `Access\Accessibility Modifiers` before `virtual`, `abstract` or `override`

So your code will be **more readable** if you write your code like everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, it is just a writing convention to write it like `public virtual`, instead of `virtual public`, Most people like this [syntax:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645760%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> method-header:
>
> **attributesopt    method-modifiersopt**   return-type   member-name   (   formal-parameter-listopt   )