# Difference between 'public static' and 'static public'

Tags: java, coding-style, modifiers

In Java, I found that some developers write:

```
public static functionName() {}
```

But some others write:

```
static public functionName() {}
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: related C# thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147668/c-sharp-public-static-vs-static-public-is-there-a-difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification, section 8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3):

> If two or more (distinct) method modifiers appear in a method
>   declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in
>   the order consistent with that shown above in the production for
>   MethodModifier.

So they can appear in any order, but there is a *recommended*
ordering. The order is:

> Annotation public protected private abstract
>   static final synchronized native strictfp

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same. But still you are missing the return type of the method.

```
public static returnType functionName(){}

static public returnType functionName(){}
```