# Is there any difference between public static function and static public function in PHP?

Tags: php, static, styles

We I declare a public static function, I always use:

```php
class Foo {
    public static function bar() {}
}
```

However, I read a library where I saw:

```php
class Foo {
    static public function bar() {} // Note the inversion of public and static
}
```

Then I tried to compare both designs in this small snippet:

```php
class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        $a = self::a();
        $b = self::b();

        var_dump($a, $b);
    }

    static public function a() {
        return "a";
    }

    public static function b() {
        return "b";
    }
}
```

As expected, I saw "a" and "b" in the debugger.

I read that in C# this is perfectly the same: [public static vs static public - is there a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147668/public-static-vs-static-public-is-there-a-difference)

But in **PHP**, is there any diffrence between the two designs or is it a pure code style choice?

Comment: Same as the difference between a "a big brown dog" and "a brown big dog".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the language there is none, but according to the coding style PSR-2 there is.

[PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#1-overview)

If you don't care about coding standards you can use both,  but I will strongly suggest you to apply the common standard.

> Visibility MUST be declared on all properties and methods; abstract and final MUST be declared before the visibility; static MUST be declared after the visibility.

One more thing, although there is no suggested way of coding in the php official documentation you can use this as your guide

[PHP-FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/)

You can find many resources there that will be helpful for all kind of relative questions to your.

Comment: Thank you very much for all those details. I stick to PSR-2 for a long time now, but it was a grey area in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same. The convention is "[public|protected|private] [static] function"

So `public static function b()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, but I really would like something which proves it. Could not find any occurence of that in the official documentation tho.