# Are the following exactly same?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static void function()
static public void function()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  They are the same.

By convention, people usually put the access modifier first.  However it has no effect on the generated IL which both end up as:

.method public hidebysig static void function() cil managed

Answer (score 7):

Yes they are essentially the same, however Microsoft perfers the access modifier to come first.

See the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c#191944) for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Either is correct. However, Microsoft recommends using a certain style for writing code. You can download StyleCop to validate code styling. I would use "public static".

Answer (score 3):

The ordering of `public` and `static` makes no difference to the compiler, though it may make a difference to anybody supporting the code.  The standard is to put the access modifier first.

Answer (score 0):

YUP.. They are same. it is just like calling names or a person 
eg: Mark John or John Mark =)