# C# Override and Access Modifier Keyword Preferred Order

Tags: c#, keyword

Which ordering is preferred for the `override` keyword and the access modifer (`public`, `private`, etc.) for methods?  Both of the following seem to compile and do the same thing:

```
    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return "access modifier first";
    }
```

```
    override public string ToString ()
    {
        return "override keyword first";
    }
```

<strike>In Java, the order of keywords is typically enforced, so this flexibility seems startling.</strike>  Apparently this flexibility is in Java, too (`static public void main (String [] args)` works...).

Comment: On the other hand, today I learned that the order of keywords is enforced in Java. (Are you talking about access modifiers + `static` + return type? Because `@Override` is an annotation in Java, so naturally it would come before an entire method declaration.)

Comment: Visual Studio auto completes override methods to `public override`.  I'd probably go with that.

Comment: Is it startling in the same way that JavaScript is not Java? C# and Java are two different languages with two fairly different grammars.

Comment: @BoltClock Actually I guess I've been wrong about Java.  I'll update the question.

Comment: See also older thread [Is there a convention to the order of modifiers in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper, a plug-in for VS which provides several coding assistants like extended auto-completion, places the access modifier first. This would indicate that even if the C# spec is more flexible, most people expect to see it this way.

It's odd though because to use ReSharper's auto-complete for a method, you would type in "override" and then IntelliSense gives a list of overridable methods. Then, when you pick one, it restructures the definition so the access modifier is first.

Comment: You don't need ReSharper for that. With just VS you can type in `override` which will give you a list of things to override. Upon selecting one, it is expanded to `public override string ToString()`.

Comment: Good to know. I've been using ReSharper since VS 2005, so for me it's become a part of the IDE to the point where what VS does and what ReSharper does on top of it is hazy.

Answer (score 0):

Totally a matter of preference, but `public override string ToString()` is seen more often.

Answer (score 0):

I never even knew you could do `override` first. Considering that Visual Studio autocompletes to `public override`, I would say stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Makes no difference really. Generally the access modifier is specified as the very first keyword in a function definition. In VS it will usually reorder your keywords for you.