# Is there a difference between "private readonly" and "readonly private"?

Tags: c#

I was just reviewing some code and noticed someone had marked member as `readonly private`. Is this different from `private readonly` in any way?

Example:

```
readonly private MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
```

I have never seen this before. I always use `private` then `readonly`. I could not find anything on MSDN (or even in the C# spec.) that mentions what order the access modifiers can appear in. Is there an article / reference somewhere?

Comment: It's fine although I too have never seen it written `readonly static`. I only know java and c# and in these languages the other usage would appear to be the convention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is no difference. Another common time this happens is `public static` vs `static public` In either case, some people might argue it's more important to have the access modifier first, while others would argue it's more important the  'special' modifiers be seen.

But no, it doesn't make any difference at all and it's purely a style choice.

Comment: I agree, It's more of what people are comfortable with. :)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter to the compiler, but it does (could) matter to the code reviewer or the next person to work on that code.

As the others have answered, the order doesn't matter.  You should be consistent in your ordering of those keywords.  I usually place scope first (`public`/`private`) and then behavior (`readonly`/`abstract`/`static`).

Pick the order that works for you and your team and stick with it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no difference. These keywords are just modifiers, their order is not important.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. Both are same.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c#191944).