# readonly static vs static readonly in C#

Tags: c#

Could anyone advise which statement is better, using `static` before or after `readonly`?

```
private readonly static string s_profileFilename = "";
```

or

```
private static readonly string s_profileFilename = "";
```

Comment: No difference..

Comment: Both are same..

Comment: `private const string s_profileFilename = "";`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191929/is-there-a-convention-to-the-order-of-modifiers-in-c

Comment: Since Resharper defaults to suggesting the order `static readonly`, that's what we always use here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two are the same!

According to the Language Spec, Section 10.5.2

> When a field-declaration includes a readonly modifier, the fields
>   introduced by the declaration are readonly fields. Direct assignments
>   to readonly fields can only occur as part of that declaration or in an
>   instance constructor or static constructor in the same class.

And Section 1.6.5

> A field declared with the static modifier defines a static field. A
>   static field identifies exactly one storage location. No matter how
>   many instances of a class are created, there is only ever one copy of
>   a static field.

The two excerpts use the word "include" and "with". This implies no order of the modifiers. They just have to be there, and they will have their effects.

Therefore, there is no answer as to which one is "better". It depends on your own (or maybe your team's) preference. For me, it's `static readonly`.

In this particular case, `static readonly` can be replaced by `const`, since a string literal is considered a constant expression (Section 7.19) and `const` is implicitly static (Section 10.4).

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in generated IL.

**Case 1:**

```
public static readonly int A;
```

Generated IL:

```
.field public static initonly int32 A
```

**Case 2:**

```
public readonly static int B;
```

Generated IL:

```
.field public static initonly int32 B
```

So it depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't care about the order of "modifiers", it treats them all the same. Check out [the Microsoft docs about modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/modifiers) for a list of all the modifiers in the language.

Personally I prefer the following order:

```
[access modifiers] [static] [readonly] [volatile]
```

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper (by default) recommends:

```
private static readonly string s_profileFilename = "";
```

but functionally they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. But for your own sanity be consistent throughout your code.

A common pattern that many people use is:
[public/private/internal] [static] [readonly]

To make this question a bit more fun, a similar parallel can be seen in English where there actually exists a common ordering of adjectives:
http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/